# Why does my question's title have "curses" prepended to it?

Tags: discussion, tags, title

I recently asked this question: [Do something while waiting for a blocking action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346673/lua-do-something-while-waiting-for-a-blocking-action)

I tagged it with "curses", because the blocking action that inspired the question was a curses function. Perhaps I shouldn't have.

Now when you look at the question, "curses" will appear at the beginning of the title. I even tried prepending "Lua" to it myself so that it would stop that, but it just caused them both to be there.

This gives people the impression that my question is primarily about curses, and they post on my question strictly in regard to curses. I might not have asked my question clearly enough, but I think this title is influencing it. Why is a (seemingly random) tag prepended to the title at all?

Comment: I guess you've been foiled. Again.

Comment: It's a black-hat SEO technique implemented by the executives, not the programmers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The system detects if the tag is in the title, and adds the first tag that's not already in the title. Since the system detected that "Lua -" was already in the title, it added the next tag, [curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curses). If all the tags have been added to the title, no prefix will be added in the title bar.

I just removed the "Lua -" section from your title and now it shows "lua -" in the title bar.

As a rule of thumb, try to work tags into your title organically - you wouldn't normally prefix a sentence in English with the subject. So, "Do something in Lua while waiting for a blocking curses call" would be fine (and take care of *two* tags).

Comment: ewww... I think prefixing the best tag makes sense, but if the system is automatically adding a tag other than the best (because it found the best already in the title), it should suffix instead.  Or just about anything other than prefix.  "Do something in Lua while waiting for a blocking call (curses)" seems a lot better than "curses - Do something in Lua while waiting for a blocking call"