# Why does stackoverflow show the wrong tag in a question page’s title?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34343688/429091) shows “jquery” in the page title (“jquery - How do I populate a form via ajax that will update a model? - Stack Overflow”) when the least popular tag associated with the question (django) is more relevant. How should the asker update the question to make it more obvious that it’s relevant to django and not something that the average jquery guru could help with?

Comment: You mean like in the title bar on my browser?  I would bet it just takes the first tag.  In any case, why is this a problem?

Comment: @Becuzz It suggests the question is focused on something it isn’t. Yes, I mean the page title when the question’s page is being viewed.

Comment: Since the software has to chose something, the first seems like a good shot. If the user doesn't put the most important first, that is just tough. Remember, the user may not even know which is the most important. If even the user doesn't, how would the software?

Comment: @binki The asker _did_ tag it with jQuery so it is relevant.  Look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252620/why-does-my-questions-title-have-curses-prepended-to-it) for an explanation as to why the title does that.  I'm not sure how you would expect the code to choose the most relevant tag.  If it could understand what kind of expertise was needed to solve the problem, well... prepare for Skynet.

Comment: But stackoverflow chooses the tags with the highest follower count instead of the most relevant tag.

Comment: It could allow you to specify the most relevant tag when editing the question or something ;-)

Comment: @binki  Or you could just put it first if it is really that important to you.  I honestly never look at the title in the tab on my browser.  At least for me, this seems like it would be a lot of work on a feature I wouldn't find useful at all.  Not sure how many other people would like that, but my completely wild and biased guess would be not a lot of people.

Comment: @Becuzz it doesn’t respect the input order. Other discussions here already state that the chosen tag is the one with the highest follower count.

Comment: Prefixing the question title with the most popular [tag] was a counter-measure against vampire sites that scrape SO content ranking higher in the Google query results.  Just an SEO hack, nothing to do with the relevance of the tags.  Otherwise a hard-to-win battle, a vampire site can simply omit the low-voted or unanswered crap and automagically become more relevant.  The odds that this Q will ever rank high ought to be close to zilch, little reason to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page title isn't really how users find questions to answer...

Users typically find questions to answer by tag, and then by the question's title. The question seems to be tagged appropriately and the title doesn't look too bad, so users who follow any of the tags will spot it in their feeds/searches.

This seems like somewhat of a non-issue.

Comment: OK, I realized this after asking the question. The tag listing pages and question feed on stackoverflow.com don’t render the tags with the title the way the page is displayed in the browser. So it doesn’t matter. k