# Selecting the main tag for a question

Tags: support, tags, title

When a question is created, the title appears preceded by the first tag. The tag selected for this is not the first one that was added, or the most appropriate, but just the first one alphabetically, which may not be that relevant to the question, just accessory.

E.g. in the thread [Relative positioning of custom controls with OpenLayers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911739/relative-positioning-of-custom-controls-with-openlayers-3), the tag selected is css-position, whereas the most relevant one is openlayers-3.

Is there any way to select which tag is included in the title?

Comment: The tags are ordered on number of questions, aka popularity. The most popular tag goes in the title. It is a bit more complex: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the order is by popularity, not alphabetically. The most popular tag that's not already in the title is always prepended to the title.

You should be able to have a less popular tag prepended by [including the more popular ones elsewhere in the title.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252621/6083675)

Of course, if the tag adds nothing to the question, you should just not use that tag.

---

Also note that there is a good reason why [Stack Exchange has this system.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556) It's not something we want to do away with, so you just need to work around it.