# What's the logic behind selecting a tag for the HTML title, and can it be improved?

Tags: discussion, tags, title

SO seems to sometimes pick a tag and place it at the start of the page's `<title>` tag. AFAICS it seems to happen when the tag in question is not already part of the question title. But how is a tag chosen among the up to five tags a question can have? I am often a bit confused when googling something due to the page's title starting with a seemingly irrelevant tag.

A few example from my own questions:

- [c# - Is it bad to skip exception constructor overloads if you're not going to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140933/is-it-bad-to-skip-exception-constructor-overloads-if-youre-not-going-to-use-the) The [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag is the least relevant of the three; [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) would be better
- [c# - Is captive depencendy OK when cache (singleton) depends on timer (transient)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973553/is-captive-depencendy-ok-when-cache-singleton-depends-on-timer-transient) Again, the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag is the least relevant. [dependency-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependency-injection) would have been the optimal choice.

Another weird one:

- [language agnostic - Shortest distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)

Would it be possible and desirable to let the user select a "primary" tag if they wished? (For example, click a tag to make it the active, click again to turn off and let SO choose.)

Comment: It's the most popular tag of the tagged tags IIRC.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326474/selecting-the-main-tag-for-a-question and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220932/295232):

> The most popular tag in the question is added to the HTML title, if it isn't found in the actual question title.

The new feature you mention, selecting a primary tag, [has already been proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326474/selecting-the-main-tag-for-a-question).